# how do I solve ValueError: Unknown load command: 50 in pyinstaller OSX

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller

I got problem while compiling all my python code after update osx. 
I found it lately after several days after upgrade high sierra to mojave. I don't know if it's os problem or pyinstaller library problem conflicts to another library.

here are the error message

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon=upload.icns --name=uploader2 apps.py
96 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.2.1
96 INFO: Python: 2.7.10
108 INFO: Platform: Darwin-18.0.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
109 INFO: wrote /Users/applemacbookpro/code/myapps/uploader/uploader2.spec
120 INFO: UPX is not available.
121 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/Users/applemacbookpro/code/myapps/uploader',
'/Users/applemacbookpro/code/myapps/uploader']
122 INFO: checking Analysis
139 INFO: Building because /Users/applemacbookpro/code/myapps/uploader/apps.py changed
139 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
147 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
208 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pyinstaller", line 9, in 
load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.2.1', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/main.py", line 90, in run
run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/main.py", line 46, in run_build
PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 788, in main
build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 734, in build
exec(text, spec_namespace)
File "", line 16, in 
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 212, in init
self.postinit()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 161, in postinit
self.assemble()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 373, in assemble
redirects=self.binding_redirects)[1:])
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/bindepend.py", line 227, in Dependencies
for lib, npth in selectImports(pth, xtrapath):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/bindepend.py", line 500, in selectImports
dlls = getImports(pth)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/bindepend.py", line 734, in getImports
return _getImports_macholib(pth)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/bindepend.py", line 621, in _getImports_macholib
m = MachO(pth)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/lib/macholib/MachO.py", line 69, in init
self.load(fp)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/lib/macholib/MachO.py", line 79, in load
self.load_fat(fh)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/lib/macholib/MachO.py", line 90, in load_fat
self.load_header(fh, arch.offset, arch.size)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/lib/macholib/MachO.py", line 114, in load_header
hdr = MachOHeader(self, fh, offset, size, magic, hdr, endian)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/lib/macholib/MachO.py", line 154, in init
self.load(fh)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/lib/macholib/MachO.py", line 186, in load
raise ValueError("Unknown load command: %d" % (cmd_load.cmd,))
ValueError: Unknown load command: 50
```

Comment: How did you install `pyinstaller`? Have you tried upgrading or reinstalling?

Comment: yes, I've tried to upgrade to latest version but failed too.
3.4.1, 3.3.1, 3.2.1 nothing works

Comment: And, again, how did you install it?

Comment: pip install --user pyinstaller

using latest pyinstaller give me this error
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 851, in resolve
        raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
    pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (altgraph 0.10.2 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python), Requirement.parse('altgraph>=0.15'), set(['macholib']))

Comment: finally I can compile it..
pip install -U --user altgraph solved it..thank you